# How to get the url of a file using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, file

I am using select folder dialog box to get multiple file. I need to parse the XML file on that folder. But iam struggle in getting the file path. Can U help me.

```
//Onclick choose path
$("input[name='file_path']").click(function(){

    $("#myInput").trigger('click');
});
$("#myInput").change(function() {
    var names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i)
    {
        var F_name= $(this).get(0).files[i].name;
        names.push(F_name);
        var extension = F_name.replace(/^.*\./, '');
        if(extension == "xml")
        {   
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET" ,
            url:  F_name,
            dataType: "xml" ,
            success: function(xml) {    

                    alert($(this).find('title-group article-title').text());                
            }

            });
        }       
    }
    $("input[name=file_path]").val(names);

});
```

Comment: Are you trying to read a file on the user's computer with ajax?

Comment: yes i have to get the files from users pc

Comment: Well you can't use ajax to do that, you can use a FileReader object to read the file data.

Comment: Can u help me i try lot but couldnt help. Pls check this path https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL#Example_reading_multiple_files but how to use in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ajax to read files on the users' file system, you can use a FileReader object to read the file data though.

```js
$("#myInput").change(function() {
    var names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i)
    {
        var F_name = this.files[i].name;
        names.push(F_name);
        var extension = F_name.replace(/^.*\./, '');
        if(extension == "xml")
        {   
            var rd = new FileReader();
            rd.onload = function(e){   
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(this.result);
                var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
                console.log($xml.find('title-group article-title').text());                
            };
            rd.readAsText(this.files[i]);
        }       
    }
    $("input[name=file_path]").val(names);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=file id=myInput multiple>
<input name=file_path>
```

Comment: Nope, what would you need that for?

Comment: The server is running on the machine you are selecting these files from?

Comment: Task is to read a date from  xml file and made changes to that xml file  from user system

Comment: The closest thing you can do is upload the file, modify it and have the user download the modified version